# How to update css/scss files with NGINX

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx

I am running a Digital Ocean droplet with Gunicorn and NGINX. I am able
to view my web pages but I am not able to update html/css/scss.

I have added `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as suggested in another post. Also tried
`python manage.py collectstatic` and received the following: `0 static files copied to '/home/ubuntuadmin/pyapps/nomad/static', 177 unmodified`

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/nomad` >>>

````
   server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 157.245.0.153;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntuadmin/pyapps/nomad;
    }

   location /media/ {
        root /home/ubuntuadmin/pyapps/nomad/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Did you clean your cache on your browser?

Comment: If I pull repo I can see the changes in ubuntu with ```cat /home/...```

Comment: yes i did command + shift R and restarted NGINX with ```sudo systemctl restart nginx```

Comment: Are you using a CDN?

Comment: No, I don't believe I am

Comment: How about your static requests on Browser Dev Tool? Just want to make sure that there is no cache data by any party. You could try to direct access to your static resource via browser to take a look at response css.

Comment: ```GET http://157.245.0.153/static/ 403 (Forbidden)```

Comment: ```Request Method: GET
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 157.245.0.153:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip```

Comment: well you can't access the /static/ folder itself, try it with an actual path to a css file. And look at the http response headers (cache headers).

Comment: Thanks for your input guys! I was able to rebuild Ubuntu distro and create a static directory in NGINX. It works and I am able to deploy.